# Enabling mcrypt on CentOS

Tags: php, centos, mcrypt

When attempting to load a Kohana3 app onto my server, I was warned that mcrypt was not enabled. How would I go about enabling mcrypt on my CentOS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean mcrypt

```
yum install php-mcrypt
```

Then restart apache

```
service httpd restart
```

Comment: I did mean "mcrypt," sorry for the confusion. The "y" naturally follows after years of writing "mysql" I suppose. This worked marvelously - thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

[php-mcrypt](http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/x86_64/repoview/php-mcrypt.html) is available in [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

Comment: Fedora and CentOS rpms can be quite different.

Comment: EPEL is for RHEL/CentOS which is clearly stated on that page.

Comment: how can i add EPEL to my repo list so that I can use "yum" to install?